How do I automate disabling and enabling a monitor on the Windows Settings?
I want to automate this function in Windows Settings.

Nirsoft's Multi-monitor tool works for the first part of disabling the monitor, but after it disables it, the monitor disappears from the list and I can't re-enable it anymore other than going to Windows Settings to re-enable it.
Is there a different tool I can use? Or is there a registry entry I can modify?

I use ActualTools Multi Monitor for this, and it works. Its not a free tool though.

@LPChip I'm assuming it's Actual Multiple Monitors? But it seems to be far more complex than just enabling and disabling a display though? I don't even see that feature on the product page

Yes indeed that prodcut. I use the Window Manager myself, which is their total suite. You basically create a desktop profile, setup which monitors are active in it, and use a keyboard shortcut to switch between desktop profiles. If a monitor is turned off in one and on in another, you effectively turn that monitor on and off by the press of a button on the keyboard.

If you go here: https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/screenshots/ and search for List of Multi-monitor Desktop Profiles and their properties, on that screen, you define the profiles. You can select a monitor and set it as disabled, and if you apply that profile, it will then turn it off. Similarly, if you have it turned on, it will do so. You can make different monitors the primary monitor for that profile, change wallpapers and so much more.

It turns out that this can be done via Powershell! Here's a step by step.

Install the DisplayConfig package for Powershell.
You're done!

Just do Enable-Display <monitor ID> or Disable-Display <monitor ID> from Powershell.
If you're using batch files, you can do powershell Enable-Display 3 for example.
The best part is it doesn't go out of position unlike the Multi-monitor Tool from nirsoft.
